# disable message box for programs that was run from cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I have util which at the end of it's work shows message box with notification and OK button. I run it under command line and would like to disable all message boxes that can break my process and require user reaction. Does any way to accoplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just adding a `--quiet` command line switch instead, so users have better control over this kind of thing.

If you want to try to do it automatically, you can check the parent PID right when your app launches, and see if it's `cmd.exe`. Of course this is not 100% accurate because there are more scenarios where users don't want user interaction.

Comment: I added `/Q` but it prevent only output from to be displayed. The problem is I can not modify this utility. I use it as is in follownig way: `Process.Start("name", "arg")` in c# and wait for exit. Now I am needed to interrupt process. Obviously it's not good and flexible decision.

Comment: There is no way to automatically turn a GUI application into one that requires no user interaction. That would actually be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you could use VBScript to automatically click or press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on the messagebox.  But you'll need to know the window name or number of the messagebox.

This code will bring focus to a Window called MESSAGEBOXNAME, and the press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.AppActivate("MESSAGEBOXNAME")
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.SendKeys "~"
```

Where `MESSAGEBOXNAME` is the Window Name of the MessageBox, that should be in the upper right corner of the messagebox.